# Extra lines getting added in Pandas `read_csv`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, keras, google-colaboratory

I am loading two different files with pandas `read_csv`. One contains sentences in English language and the other contains sentences in Hindi language. In the `txt` file, both have equal number of sentences. But when I am loadng the file in Google Colab, the number of rows is chaning due to which there is an error later on.

This is the english sentence file loaded though pandas.

```
                                                       eng
0           Give your application an accessibility workout
1                        Accerciser Accessibility Explorer
2           The default plugin layout for the bottom panel
3              The default plugin layout for the top panel
4           A list of plugins that are disabled by default
...                                                    ...
1565202           The programme will be streamed live via:
1565203  Ministry of Education Facebook Page: https://w...
1565204                                UGC YouTube Channel
1565205  UGC Twitter Handle (@ugc_india) : https://twit...
1565206             It would also be broadcast on DD News.

[1565207 rows x 1 columns]
```

And this is the Hindi language file loaded through pandas

```
                                                        hi
0          अपने अनुप्रयोग को पहुंचनीयता व्यायाम का लाभ दें
1                          एक्सेर्साइसर पहुंचनीयता अन्वेषक
2                    निचले पटल के लिए डिफोल्ट प्लग-इन खाका
3                     ऊपरी पटल के लिए डिफोल्ट प्लग-इन खाका
4        उन प्लग-इनों की सूची जिन्हें डिफोल्ट रूप से नि...
...                                                    ...
1573683    कार्यक्रम को इनके जरिए लाइव स्ट्रीम किया जाएगा:
1573684  मानव संसाधन विकास मंत्रालय का फेसबुक पेज: http...
1573685                                यूजीसी यूट्यूब चैनल
1573686  यूजीसी ट्विटर हैंडल (@ugc_india) : https://twi...
1573687  कार्यक्रम को डीडी न्यूज पर भी प्रसारित किया जा...

[1573688 rows x 1 columns]
```

As we can see there are different number of rows in both these dataframes. Whereas, in the original `txt` file both have 1609682 sentences each.

Comment: Does both files contain same number of lines as sentences? Since you are using read_csv, what's the separator?

Answer (score 0):

I saw something similar in my own work a short time ago. The issues was an inconsistent use of line breaks and character returns, as separators.  It's impossible to know exactly what yo are dealing with, because you didn't share any sample data that would indicate what your real issue is.  You can open your file in Notepad++ and 'see' all the line breaks and character returns and any/all other non-printable characters.

Remember, the '\n character' is a line feed and the '\r' is a carriage return.

Try something like this.

To remove line breaks using Python see example:

```
//Removes all 3 types of line breaks
string = string.replace("\r","")
string = string.replace("\n","")
```

https://texthandler.com/info/remove-line-breaks-python/

Comment: Yes, I tried this also but it didn't work. Also used `utf-8` encoding but that also didn't work.